# SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed Failed to enable crypto

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, xampp, composer-php

When I try install to composer on my system, it always gives me this error

```
    The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I used the php -r 'print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());' command to see the php default cert locations and the result is below:

```
    Array
(
    [default_cert_file] => C:\usr\local\ssl/cert.pem
    [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
    [default_cert_dir] => C:\usr\local\ssl/certs
    [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
    [default_private_dir] => C:\usr\local\ssl/private
    [default_default_cert_area] => C:\usr\local\ssl
    [ini_cafile] => C:\xampp\apache\cert.pem
    [ini_capath] =>
)
```

C:\usr\local\ssl/cert.pem does not exist so I then downloaded an ssl cert from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and manually created the C:\usr\local\ssl/cert.pem but still no success.
I really need a solution as I'm out of options or is there a way I can bypass the ssl cert validation.